# Keeping an Activity alive when browsing through the app in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I currently have an Activity A with a fragment inside that the user can interact with, the goal here is to simply "background" Activity A and fragment and allow the user to use the rest of the app normally with a floating button that when pressed the user will be taken back to Activity A and the UI will be restored the same as the user left it. I've looked into onSaveInstanceState but that only applies to when the system ends it or when screen rotation happens and not when the user presses the back button. So is it possible to save Activity A with the same UI and restore it at any given time?

Edit: I also have no way of accessing/modifying the fragment's components since it's coming from an SDK already.

Comment: I think what you're asking to to preserve the state of fragment A.  Activity A will always be active if you have a bunch of fragments that it is managing.

Comment: The main issue here is that I have no access to the fragment's UI elements since it's coming from an SDK